# Conflict with Protobuf versions using Gstreamer

Tags: ubuntu, protocol-buffers, gstreamer, protoc

I have a bit of a strange question

I am compiling an application on a VM with **protoc 3.6.1** installed. 
It then build a zip file which I scp over to another machine where I unzip it and run it.

***None of the commands I run on that machine should require using protocol buffers.***

```
     loop = g_main_loop_new( NULL, FALSE );
     gst_init(NULL, NULL);
     snprintf( str_pipeline, sizeof( str_pipeline ), "appsrc name=mysource ! videoconvert ! " "video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080,format=NV12 ! vaapih264enc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! " "udpsink host=%s port=5600", "xxx.xx.xx.xxx");

    // Instruct GStreamer to construct the pipeline 
    pipeline = gst_parse_launch( str_pipeline, &gerror );

    if( !pipeline )
    {
       printf( "gst_parse_launch error. Cannot launch GStreamer..: %s\n", gerror->message );

      return false;
    }

    appsrc = gst_bin_get_by_name( GST_BIN( pipeline ), "mysource" );
    app_caps = gst_caps_new_simple( "video/x-raw", "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "RGB", "width", G_TYPE_INT, WIDTH, "height", G_TYPE_INT, HEIGHT, NULL );
```

However, when I run the above code the gstreamer command (in particular gst_parse_launch() ), that gives me this error -

```
[libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:79] This program was compiled against version 2.6.1 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, which is not compatible with the installed version (3.6.1).  Contact the program author for an update.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "/build/mir-O8_xaj/mir-0.26.3+16.04.20170605/obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/src/protobuf/mir_protobuf.pb.cc".)
```

I do not think gstreamer has anything to do with protoc but I wanted to confirm that. Is gstreamer 1.0 compiled with protoc 2.6.1 ?

If that is not the case, why am I getting this error on the VM where I unzip ? It does not have protoc installed and is running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Could you add a few more details? Like what pipeline is it, why is protobuf involved ? also give some snippet to work on.

Comment: @RC0993 - I can post my code. As to why is protobuf is involved, that is kinda my question here. I dont know why gstreamer would care about protobuf.

Comment: **_"I dont know why gstreamer would care about protobuf"_** Exactly my doubt

Comment: @RC0993 - updated post with code snippet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you say and I can see, that there is no use of protobuf here.

In such case, the first thing I suspect is that *some random file* of yours is pointing to *some file* of protobuf on your machine, while the compilation. (I am not sure why though). A safe thing to do here is to uninstall protoc (all versions).
you can choose how to uninstall depending on your OS.

Then try compiling it again. may be that might show us some way *to heaven peacefully* :P

**EDIT1:**

I have tried this on my system *(I have gstreamer and protobuf and grpc all installed)*

```
str_pipeline ="audiotestsrc ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink";

cout << str_pipeline << endl;

// Instruct GStreamer to construct the pipeline
pipeline = gst_parse_launch(static_cast<const gchar*>(str_pipeline), &gerror);

if (!pipeline) {
    printf("gst_parse_launch error. Cannot launch GStreamer..: %s\n",
            gerror->message);

    return false;
}
```

and I am not getting the same error as you. (may be you can try this on yours)

The error I am getting is:

```
GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_parse_launch_full: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
```

Comment: I can try that. The weird thing is, if I comment that call out to see if any of the other calls to gstreamer functions get the same error, they don't. They get assertion errors due to NULL pipeline which is expected. Im not sure if its just that particular call or what. Maybe I can also try installing protoc on this new VM as well where the application is running. Currently it does not have it installed since I did not think it was necessary.

Comment: Hey @maddog2323 Check the updated answer ( I will have to delete that update after this discussion maybe - as that do not qualify the "Answer" category):)

Comment: @maddog2323 Did you reach somewhere with this?

Comment: sorry I have been traveling the past week. I will try your suggestion this weekend and get back to you. Thanks